# Creating - importing database issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'v made a huge mistake. It's 5 am for me currently, so i didnt think it trough. I'm complete newbie.

Basically, what i did is this. Bought a vps to learn , added site and all configuration. When i was done, it was the next step to add some posts. Since i do have from my old site a backup of mysql i decided just to import it and have all posts in a minute.

I created a new database with the same name as of my old database and hit import. Problem is it ruined everything. My url points to old url (from old database and asks for old site url).

How i can revert this or fix it whithout deleting a whole vps and starting over.

Thanks

Comment: What software are you running? Aside from the URL being the old URL, what else is ruined exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CPanel ? Are you keeping the previous database backup file somewhere.